# create a service to detect settings open

Tags: android

As I am an administrator of users' mobile which is provided by my company, I need to restrict the user from opening the settings. I want to create a service to detect when the settings are being opened. But I cannot find which intent I need to monitor in service code and manifest xml?

For example,

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);


<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMT_SET"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

the above is the example I search in web, but I don't know which intent represent of SETTINGS.

Answer (score 2):

> As I am an administrator of users' mobile which is provided by my company, I need to restrict the user from opening the settings.

Create your own custom build of the Android OS that locks down the Settings app, package that custom build into your own custom ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on the devices that you are distributing.

Comment: Since we only install a small app into our phone, we will not create our own custom build Android OS. Have you having other method suggests?

Comment: @Anthony: Then do not attempt to restrict the user from opening Settings. Bear in mind that they can do that anyway, simply by rebooting the device in safe mode.

Comment: thanks to remind me the safe mode which I am by pass to consider. Can you have any suggestions to me? I am trying ActivityManager now, it is work to detect SETTINGS. But I place the code in onCreate() and run only once. I don't know how to monitor the system automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 ways wich both have their (dis-)advanteges.

1) You can detect if your app is going to the background which happens when the user opens the menu. The handler is:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
```

There you can close ALL system menus, even the menu to reboot or turn off the device!
This is done with this intent:

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

2) You can start a run a service with a background worker that is checking the front app very often (like twice a second). You can get the foreground app like this:

```
String packageName;
String className;
ActivityManager amen = (ActivityManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
packageName = amen.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
className = amen.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

The package name for the settings is: **com.android.settings**

If you detect it you can simply start an intent that brings your app back to the foreground.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Write a `Service` to read system `LogCat`, when an application starts, it will display a very unique log. For example, this is the log when start `Gmail` application.

```
08-31 16:42:28.650: I/ActivityManager(3905): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail bnds=[240,384][360,534]} from pid 7290
```

Well, for your case, just compare the `cmp=` if it equals `com.android.settings`, then do what you need to do.

Comment: You are aware of changes in log access in JB and that "do what you want" may be quite restricted if you are not rooted?

Comment: As Said by @WebnetMobile.com, this will not work on JellyBean where apps may not read anything but their own logs.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I cannot use intent of "com.android.settings" in service to detect the SETTINGS. Is the same intent name in service and manifest?

Comment: @Anthony: it's not `Intent`, it's about reading log information...zzz

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, @GuyKun: thanks for the information, but do the author of the post really mean that his `Service` will be running on `JellyBean` only?

Comment: @xjaphx: Developers need to understand the limitation of script-kiddie approaches like the one that you are recommending. Hence, it is useful to let developers know that this approach will stop working with Jelly Bean (and could conceivably stop working with earlier versions of Android, if Google elects to impose this restriction via OS patches).

Comment: @CommonsWare: I know that, but it's always better if Google provides in-depth information for developers, rather than just some developers find and tell to community. I like Android but I cannot find enough information everytime Android updates; while Microsoft always update the MSDN. I don't try to compare anything, but if the documentation for Android, having more details, it's gonna be really awesome!!!